# Recover after exception

Tags: python-3.x, api, loops, tweepy

How can i recover from exception and continue line string from opened file? I'm stuck!

```
    try:
while True:
    with open('us.txt') as f:
        for user in f:
            for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user, ).items():
                print(tweet.user.screen_name)
                csvWriter.writerow(tweet.user.screen_name)
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
print(e.reason)
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your (admittedly a bit confusing) question is asking how to ignore the exception, but still continue from where you were in the file, you should try and keep your `try:` and `except:` blocks as close to the problematic line.

For example, if `csvWriter.writerow(tweet.user.screen_name)` is the line which fails, you could do:

```
while True:
    with open('us.txt') as f:
        for user in f:
            for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user,).items():
                print(tweet.user.screen_name)
                try:
                    csvWriter.writerow(tweet.user.screen_name)
                except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                    print(e)
```

If instead the error is in the `for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(...` line, you could do this:

```
while True:
    with open('us.txt') as f:
        for user in f:
            try:
                for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user,).items():
                    print(tweet.user.screen_name)
                    csvWriter.writerow(tweet.user.screen_name)
            except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                print(e)
```

I hope this helps!